# How to capture dynamic token in jmeter

Tags: dynamic, jmeter, token

We have an app that passes __RequestVerificationToken value. I am using css/jquery as:

**Name of created variable:** token
**css/jquery exression:** name=__RequestVerificationToken
**Attribute:** value

and I am passing ${token} to http request. Still I dnt see value is passing token.

Token format is:

**__RequestVerificationToken: jSGDdGDPAnepAa5NFV_w05mDntg-3O7Jh3bnyJvcXZlEShERWPjQbbC5bH6qc7vmoAXUPSj3FHjzdVCwxqE5BF5_j7jhhIeStq6a89EBufORwpB1MPha3gmHeGgCb8ivtFCm3Iplyj17RiPAUOuz-1zdq0hB08es9Rozekq5vOY1**

Answer (score 0):

Check the below RegEx and output, if this fits your requirement:-

[image][image]

Hope this helps.